# convert an array of objects to one object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to convert an array of objects to one object of objects. My function works but I don't want key name before each object.

```
 myArray = [{
     "name": "ann",
      "y": 191,
      "color": "red"
    },{
     "name": "mary",
      "y": 11,
      "color": "red"
    },{
     "name": "henry",
      "y": 11,
      "color": "red"
    }]

let result = {};
for (let item of seriesTotal) {
  result[item.name] = item;
delete item.name;
}
```

I'd like this

```
myObject = {{
 "name": "ann",
  "y": 191,
  "color": "red"
},{
 "name": "mary",
  "y": 11,
  "color": "red"
},{
 "name": "henry",
  "y": 11,
  "color": "red"
}{
```

Comment: what you want is not a valid js object.

Comment: As mentioned, that is not a valid object, so instead tell how you want to use it by providing us with a working code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a **name (or key)** and a value.

You can use the index as the key or property name. Use `Object.assign` to create a new object. Use `map` and spread syntax to loop thru the array.

```js
let myArray = [{
  "name": "ann",
  "y": 191,
  "color": "red"
}, {
  "name": "mary",
  "y": 11,
  "color": "red"
}, {
  "name": "henry",
  "y": 11,
  "color": "red"
}];


let result = Object.assign(...myArray.map((o,i) => ({[i]: o})));

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is not valid JS object, you'll get an string in JS, so you could use `.replace()`:

```
    myArray = JSON.stringify(myArray).replace(/(\[)(.+)(\])/g,"{$2}");

    console.log(myArray);

//{{"name":"ann","y":191,"color":"red"},{"name":"mary","y":11,"color":"red"},{"name":"henry","y":11,"color":"red"}}
```

But as I said before, that is not a JS object, it's just a string.